# Best data base in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, watson-iot

I am new to Bluemix. I am planning for a web application that could utilize the database service and Watson IoT service.
Currenlty I am using mysql for my app, because it is more familiar to me.  I have noticed couple of other services too( clearDB, dashDB, Cloudant DB, NoSQLCloudantDB ). I am not sure whether all the terms i mentioned is correct.

I am confused, which service should i follow?. 
For mysql, How can I see the tables that I pushed?.
And, what is meant by, cloudantNoSQL?.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Watson IoT platform provides a managed connector to the IBM Cloudant NoSQL DB service on Bluemix. https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2016/07/25/enhanced-data-storage-capabilities-for-ibm-watson-iot-platform/

A single specific storage solution is not going to work for every case so which option you choose may be dependent on your overall architecture and strategy.

Comment: Cloudant is an open-source database based on Apache CouchDB and offered on the Bluemix Cloud by IBM. It is non-relational, hence NoSQL. You can learn more about it at https://cloudant.com.

Comment: Thanks ValerieLampkin! Do you have any suggestion for large amount data from, large number of devices?.

Comment: Correction: While CloudantDB itself is not open source, CouchDB -- which it based on -- **is** (Apache licensed).